# Как программно отключить темную тему в приложении Android?

Tags: java, android, android-themes

На новых Android, доступна функция включения темной темы для всего устройства и соответственно адаптация приложений под темные цвета. Но эта адаптация изменяет мое приложение на некоторых устройствах (самое главное что это происходит не всех устройствах), делая темный текст на темном фоне, соответственно делая его нечитабельным, тоже самое происходит с другими элементами, что выглядит ужасно и непрактично. Можно ли как то отключить принудительную адаптацию под темную тему программно в приложении?

Answer (score 2):

```
 //системная тема
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
 //light тема
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
 //ночная тема
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```